# I am trying to create a PROCEDURE that INSERTS values via paramerters but it's not working

Tags: mysql

```sql
DELIMITER &&
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_row_in_emp_table;
CREATE PROCEDURE add_row_in_emp_table
(
    empcode VARCHAR(15),
    empname VARCHAR(15),
    deptcode VARCHAR(15),
    birthdate DATE,
    sex CHAR(1),
    desigcode varchar(15),
    supcode varchar(15),
    gradecode varchar(15),
    gradelevel varchar(15),
    basicpay varchar(15)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO emp
    (empcode)
    values(
    empcode,empname,deptcode,birthdate,sex,desigcode,
    supcode,gradecode,gradelevel,basicpay
    );
END &&
DELIMITER ;
```

it is showing commands out of sync. can you please explain what is wrong?
i also tried using session variables that also is not working

Comment: The published code does not throw an error and compiles..So I'm guessing you get the error when you call the procedure? If so you should add this info to the question with the full call statement. If error is thrown in some other way please add what process caused it. nb the insert statement is nonsense and wouldn't work standalone review insert here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html and you should never give parameter names which are the same as column names.

Answer (score 0):

Use columns name if few columns value are inserted. But if all columns value are inserted then columns name using are not mandatory but may be a chance for data type mismatch. Also passing session value with parameter or handle with variable inside procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_row_in_emp_table (IN ecode varchar(15),IN ename varchar(15))
BEGIN
    insert into emp (empcode, empname) values (ecode,ename);
END
```

**N.B.:** use columns name for inserting data or selecting data for better readability

Please check this **url** https://dbfiddle.uk/ODxp-NFH